# How to show TeamCity builds from non-default branch

Tags: rest, teamcity

I would like to to see all builds from a specific build type. To get them I am using this URL:

```
[team-city]/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:[build-type]/builds
```

However, this only shows builds from the default branch. In my project I am using git-flow, so I do not have a single default branch. I have a lot branches, per feature/version. How do I get (by REST) builds for those branches?

Comment: I am not sure whether you will essentially need to use REST for the above. I will post my suggestion below. Its very easy.

Answer (score 6):

I was just looking at a similar issue,  i resolved it by including:

```
branch:(unspecified:any)
```

in this context:

```
/guestAuth/app/rest/builds/?locator=status:SUCCESS,number:<mybuildnumber>,branch:(unspecified:any)
```

Where **mybuildnumber** is self explanatory. This URL found a specific build i was looking for from non-default branch